# Overriding Methods

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I would like help with his problem. I cant find anything on this topic. (maybe I'm searching the wrong thing)

Define a subclass of C named B that overrides method `m1()` so that it returns the difference between m and n.

```
public class C
{
    private int m;
    private int n;

    public C(int mIn, int nIn)
    {
        m = mIn;
        n = nIn;
    }
    public int m1()
    {
        return m+n;
    }
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Third search result on google for 'java override' -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?  You don't know how to do it?

Comment: What is the specific problem here?  Are you familiar with the idea of subclassing?  Overriding?  Have you looked these terms up in whatever textbook you're learning Java from?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good SO questions.

Comment: I'm just very confused overall...

Comment: @RobertAnthonySvec: "very confused" isn't a very helpful description ;)  What, specifically, are you confused about?

Comment: sorry im just very stressed. I dont understand overriding methods.

Comment: omg now im completely lost @Smit whatever, ill just go on without this.

Comment: @RobertAnthonySvec Comment deleted. But if you dont understand this topic then it will be hard to survive in programming.

Comment: Well if i get help and not constant comments that would be helpful

Comment: @Robert: This stuff is explained (with examples) in any introductory Java textbook.  Regurgitating such explanations on Stack Overflow is ultimately not a good use of anyone's time.  So the best help anyone can give you here is to direct you to read the relevant chapters, and to not put the book down until you understand the concept !  (Or until you hit a specific question, and then feel free to ask that here...)

Comment: @Oil all im asking is for VISUAL help thats why i came to SO because i can VISUALLY see the solution/s. i am a VISUAL learner if you didnt see that already

Comment: Please realise that what you're asking for is not a good use of SO.  You aren't asking a concrete question about a specific problem that you've hit, you're essentially just asking people to do your (homework?) question for you.  Any explanation beyond simply giving you the answer will replicate an equivalent explanation that you'd find in your textbook.  In summary: if you would like specific help, then you need to ask a specific question.

Comment: what youre saying is find the answer in the book where a teacher would give you a similar situation to aid you in finding the answer to your problem

Comment: No, I'm saying find the **explanation of overriding** in a book, and then ask a specific question if there's some specific part of that explanation you don't understand.  SO doesn't exist to save you having to look things up occasionally ;)

Answer (score 3):

First, `m` and `n` need to be `protected`, not `private` (`protected` is the default). Then just do something like:

```
public class B extends C {
    public int m1() { return m - n; }
}
```

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to give direct solutions to (apparent) homework questions...

Comment: i cant change private to public or protected. Im not allowed to change the C class

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: you are right, this is not supposed to be a homework forum. But on the other hand a direct solution is way better (to understand) than just some comments, that the question wasn't good enough.

Comment: Thanks @GameDroids i kind of get it but i cant change the C class

Answer (score 0):

You said, you can't change the `C` class, and since `m`and `n`are `private` and `C` doesn't have any getters and setters, you actually *can't* use `m` or `n` in your subclass `B`. What you could do is initialize your `B`class with it's own `m`and `n`. 
Something like that:

```
public class B extends C{
    private int bm;
    private int bn;

    public B(int mIn, int nIn){
       super(mIn,nIn);
       this.bm=mIn;
       this.bn=nIn;
    }

    @Override
    public int m1(){
       // and then you can use the B's n and m
       return this.bm - this.bn;
    }
}
```

then you can do something like this:

```
C myClass = new B( 1, 2);
int difference = B.m1();
```

**But**, if the `C`class where any different this may not work. When you are not allowed to change `C` then in normal cases you wouldn't even know what `C` looks like exactly, especially not that it has the variables `m`and `n` or if they change somewhere in another method of `C`.